# SAP fails on 2nd iteration of loop: the control could not be found by id

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

**Problem:** The 2nd loop of `For j` fails on the line of code where I "Test for which line accrual is on 66-71"

```
Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
```

This *was* working a few weeks ago but my IT and our SAP consultant advise nothing has changed..

**Error:**

> Run-time error '619'. The control could not be found by id

**Attempts:** I have tried a few error trappings, included in my code below, but nothing works.

I have done a lot of research but come up blank. I've also re-recorded the macro and nothing has changed.. I'm lost and looking for help!

**EDIT**

**Alternate Resolution:** How can I get all items/amounts/string on this ROW

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[11]").Text - row 11
```

**END OF EDIT**

**Code:**

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub SAP_TPM_Payment()
    

    'Declare Variables
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks_TPM As Worksheet
    Dim LR_TPM_A As Long, LR_TPM_E As Long, LR_DeletedSku As Long, AccAmt As Long, LR_Copy As Long, LR_clearing As Long, PayEntries As Long, PayCount As Long
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult, Response2 As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim WSHshell, proc
    
    Dim wkb2 As String, wkb2_fname As String
    Dim wkb2_name As String
    
    Dim dblStartTime As Double         'time elapsed counter
    Dim strMinutesElapsed As String
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, c As Long
    Dim Amt, Amt1, Amt2, Amt3, Amt4, Amt5, Amt6
    Dim LR_TPM_J As Long, Line, AccRow
    Dim Status, sku, SAP_Acc, SAP_Pay, ClearNo, SAP_Accrual, PayAmt, Customer
    Dim Pcheck1, Pcheck2
    Dim CustomerName
    
    Dim SapGuiAuto
    Dim SAPApp As GuiApplication
    Dim SAPCon As GuiConnection
    Dim session As GuiSession

    'Set Variables
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks_TPM = wkb.Sheets("TPM Payment")
    
    'Timer
    dblStartTime = Timer
    'Speed up code
    NeedForSpeed
         
    'Start Code
    If wks_TPM.Range("Q2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "No claim no. - exiting sub"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    wks_TPM.Range("H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Application.UserName
    wks_TPM.Range("H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 2) = Date
     
    'Gets unique Accruals from col 'A', copies to col 'E'
    If wks_TPM.Range("A4") = "" Then
        wks_TPM.Range("E3:F3").Value = wks_TPM.Range("A3:B3").Value
    Else:
        LR_TPM_A = wks_TPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wks_TPM.Range("A2:A" & LR_TPM_A).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wks_TPM.Range("E2"), Unique:=True
    End If
    
    'Sums unique Accruals from col 'B', copies to col 'F'
    LR_TPM_E = wks_TPM.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LR_TPM_E
        wks_TPM.Range("F" & i).Value = Application.SumIf(wks_TPM.Range("A:A"), wks_TPM.Range("E" & i), wks_TPM.Range("B:B"))
    Next i
       
    'Checks if SAP is open
    On Error GoTo ErrRef
    Response = MsgBox("Are you logged into SAP?" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Click 'Yes' if you are already logged into SAP" & vbCrLf & "Click 'No' to log into SAP" & vbCrLf & "Click 'Cancel' will exit the macro", vbYesNoCancel, "SAP Login Query")
    If Response = vbNo Then
        Set WSHshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set proc = WSHshell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")
        Response2 = MsgBox("Are you logged into SAP?" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Click 'Ok' once you have logged into SAP" & vbCrLf & "Click 'Cancel' will exit the macro", vbOKCancel, "SAP Login Query")
        If Response2 = vbCancel Then
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "Exiting macro...", 1, "SAP Login Query"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf Response = vbCancel Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "Exiting macro...", 1, "SAP Login Query"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
    Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
    Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
    Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
    
    For j = 3 To LR_TPM_E
    

        session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
        
        LR_TPM_J = wks_TPM.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        SAP_Accrual = wks_TPM.Range("E" & j).Value
        wks_TPM.Range("I" & LR_TPM_J + 1).Value = SAP_Accrual
  
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVBO2"
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRV13A-KNUMA_BO").Text = SAP_Accrual
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        
        'Confirms accrual is still active and not closed
        Status = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKONA-BOSTA").Text
        If Status = "" Then
            wks_TPM.Range("N" & LR_TPM_J + 1) = "Open"
        Else
            wks_TPM.Range("J" & LR_TPM_J + 1 & ":O" & LR_TPM_J + 1) = "Closed"
            GoTo NextAccrual:
        End If
        
        'Confirms accrual is for the correct customer
        Customer = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKURGV-NAME1").Text
        CustomerName = Split(Customer)(UBound(Split(Customer)))

        If CustomerName = wks_TPM.Range("Q3") Then
            wks_TPM.Range("Q4") = "Rebate Recipient matches claim"
        Else
            wks_TPM.Range("Q4") = "Rebate Recipient doesn't match claim"
            GoTo NextAccrual:
        End If
        
        'Sales Volume (scrape accruals remaining)
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 17
        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Dim Cust As String
        Cust = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3,9]").Text
        Dim CustPos As Long
        CustPos = InStr(Cust, "a")
        Debug.Print Cust
        Debug.Print CustPos
        
        ''Test for which line amt is on
        'Accrual sometimes on row 66-71, code for possibilities
        Dim g
        For g = 66 To 71
            On Error GoTo Next_g:
            Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
            If IsEmpty(Amt) = False Then
                If Amt <> "" Then
                    'Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
                    Debug.Print Amt & CStr(g)
                    'On Error GoTo 0
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print CStr(g) & "nope"
            End If
Next_g:
            'On Error GoTo 0
        Next g
        
        
              
'        On Error Resume Next
'        Amt1 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[66,11]").Text
'        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'            Err.Clear
'        End If
'        Amt2 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[67,11]").Text
'        Amt3 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[68,11]").Text
'        Amt4 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[69,11]").Text
'        Amt5 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[70,11]").Text
'        Amt6 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[71,11]").Text
'        On Error GoTo 0
        
''        'Accrual sometimes on row 66-71, code for possibilities
''        On Error GoTo Handler1:
''        Amt1 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[66,11]").Text
''Waypoint1:
''        On Error GoTo Handler2:
''        Amt2 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[67,11]").Text
''Waypoint2:
''        On Error GoTo Handler3:
''        Amt3 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[68,11]").Text
''Waypoint3:
''        On Error GoTo Handler4:
''        Amt4 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[69,11]").Text
''Waypoint4:
''        On Error GoTo Handler5:
''        Amt5 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[70,11]").Text
''Waypoint5:
''        On Error GoTo Handler6:
''        Amt6 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[71,11]").Text
''        On Error GoTo 0


        
        'AccAmt used for payment
        AccAmt = LR_TPM_J + 1
        
        ''''''''''
        'Amt Code'
        ''''''''''
        'If IsEmpty(Amt) = False And Amt <> "" Then
            Line = LR_TPM_J + 1
            AccRow = -1

ReRun:

                '********************
            Dim ScrollBarPosOrig As Long, ScrollBarPosNew As Long, ScrollBarPosUpdate As Long
            ScrollBarPosOrig = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position
            session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position = 2
            ScrollBarPosUpdate = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position


            If ScrollBarPosUpdate = ScrollBarPosOrig Then
                GoTo ScrollBarNone:
            Else
                GoTo ScrollBar:
            End If

ScrollBarNone:

            For k = 10 To 100 Step 2  '1024 to act like infinity
                sku = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3," & CStr(k) & "]").Text
                If sku = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Exit For"
                End If
                wks_TPM.Range("J" & Line) = Split(sku)(UBound(Split(sku)))  'gets last numbr from string, which is the sku/material
                wks_TPM.Range("I" & Line) = SAP_Accrual

                Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & "," & CStr(k + 1) & "]").Text
                If Right(Amt, 1) = "-" Then  'Converts to number
                        wks_TPM.Range("K" & Line).Value = Left(Amt, Len(Amt) - 1)
                        Else: wks_TPM.Range("K" & Line).Value = "0" 'Zero $$ is the amount is a debit (overpaid accrual)
                End If

                Line = Line + 1
                AccRow = AccRow + 1

            Next k

ScrollBar:

            session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position = 0
            ScrollBarPosOrig = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position

            For k = 2 To 1000 Step 2  '1024 to act like infinity

                sku = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3,10]").Text
                If sku = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Exit For"
                End If
                wks_TPM.Range("J" & Line) = Split(sku)(UBound(Split(sku)))  'gets last numbr from string, which is the sku/material
                wks_TPM.Range("I" & Line) = SAP_Accrual

                Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
                If Right(Amt, 1) = "-" Then  'Converts to number
                        wks_TPM.Range("K" & Line).Value = Left(Amt, Len(Amt) - 1)
                        Else: wks_TPM.Range("K" & Line).Value = "0" 'Zero $$ is the amount is a debit (overpaid accrual)
                End If

                Line = Line + 1
                AccRow = AccRow + 1

                On Error Resume Next
                SAP_Acc = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3,13]").Text
                Debug.Print Split(SAP_Acc)(UBound(Split(SAP_Acc)))
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                Debug.Print SAP_Accrual 'testing
                
                If Split(SAP_Acc)(UBound(Split(SAP_Acc))) = CStr(SAP_Accrual) Then
                    GoTo EndOfAccrual:
                End If

                session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position = k

            Next k

        
EndOfAccrual:
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        'Copy delete sku formula
        wks_TPM.Range("O2").Copy
        wks_TPM.Range("O" & LR_TPM_J + 1 & ":O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        'Only calculates changed/updated cells
        Application.Calculate
        'Format cells
        wks_TPM.Range("O3:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        
        'If any sku is "marked for deletion", change amount to 0
        LR_DeletedSku = wks_TPM.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For n = LR_TPM_J + 1 To LR_DeletedSku
            If wks_TPM.Range("O" & n) = "X" Then
                wks_TPM.Range("K" & n) = "0"
            End If
        Next n

        'Copy amount to be paid formula
        wks_TPM.Range("M2").Copy
        wks_TPM.Range("M" & LR_TPM_J + 1 & ":M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        'Only calculates changed/updated cells
        Application.Calculate
        'Format cells
        wks_TPM.Range("M3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
        wks_TPM.Range("M3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        'Go back one screen (equivalent of "F3")
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3

        'Payment of Accrual
        PayAmt = wks_TPM.Range("M" & AccAmt).Value
        PayEntries = Line - AccAmt
        If PayAmt <> "No" Then 'Pay Claim
            session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 24  'Pay (equivalent of "Shift+F12")

            'Test if there is a scrollbar

            ScrollBarPosOrig = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position
            ScrollBarPosNew = ScrollBarPosOrig + (o + 1)
            ScrollBarPosUpdate = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position

            If ScrollBarPosUpdate = ScrollBarPosOrig Then
                GoTo ScrollBarNonePay:
            Else
                GoTo ScrollBarPay:
            End If

ScrollBarNonePay:

            For o = 0 To PayEntries
                PayAmt = wks_TPM.Range("M" & AccAmt).Value
                session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMV13A:3007/txtKONPD-BZWRT[" & CStr(o) & ",48]").Text = PayAmt
                session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                AccAmt = AccAmt + 1
                PayEntries = PayEntries - 1

                If PayEntries = 0 Then
                    GoTo SavePayment:
                End If

            Next o

ScrollBarPay:

            For o = 0 To PayEntries
                PayAmt = wks_TPM.Range("M" & AccAmt).Value
                session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMV13A:3007/txtKONPD-BZWRT[0,48]").Text = PayAmt
                session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
                AccAmt = AccAmt + 1
                PayEntries = PayEntries - 1

                If PayEntries = 0 Then
                    GoTo SavePayment:
                End If

                session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Position = (o + 1)
            Next o

        Else: GoTo NextAccrual:
        End If

SavePayment:

        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

        'Saves payment
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

        'Press "Enter" to go back into agreement
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        'Selects rebate paymnts -> rebate docs
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[3]/menu[3]").Select
        'Selects partial settelment
        session.FindById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
        'Selects first line
        session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/cntlCUSTOM_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").SelectItem "000000000001", "COL0"
        session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/cntlCUSTOM_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ClickLink "000000000001", "COL0"
        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        'Selects Sales Doc -> Change
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]").Select
        'Need to wait a couple of seconds for SAP to save - needs 2 secs, tried 1 sec but fails
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        'Updated date to today
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4415/ctxtVBKD-FKDAT").Text = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        'Claim no.
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/txtVBKD-BSTKD").Text = wks_TPM.Range("Q2")
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        'Selects Sales Document -> Billing -> Save
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[8]").Select
        'Get Clearing Doc no.
        ClearNo = session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
        If Split(ClearNo, Chr$(32))(1) Like "*6*" Then
            wks_TPM.Range("L" & AccAmt - 1) = Split(ClearNo, Chr$(32))(1)
        End If
        'Enter thru "warning"
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        'Get Clearing Doc no. take 2 as enter thru errors producs different status bar text
        ClearNo = session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
        If wks_TPM.Range("L" & AccAmt - 1) = "" Then
            If Split(ClearNo, Chr$(32))(1) Like "*6*" Then
                wks_TPM.Range("L" & AccAmt - 1) = Split(ClearNo, Chr$(32))(1)
            End If
        End If
        session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

        'Need to wait a second for SAP to catch up
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

NextAccrual:
    
    Next j
   
    'Copy clearing doc no.
    For c = 3 To LR_TPM_A
        wks_TPM.Range("C" & c).Value = Application.SumIf(wks_TPM.Range("I:I"), wks_TPM.Range("A" & c), wks_TPM.Range("L:L"))
    Next c
   
    Dim pathTPM_temp As String
    Dim fnameTPM_temp As String
    
    'Enter VB05N trans to get payment details
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVA05N"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSKUNNR-LOW").Text = ""
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtPBSTKD").Text = wks_TPM.Range("Q2")
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
    'Export to 'local file'
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 45
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").Select
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
    pathTPM_temp = "C:\Users\adamsmit\Desktop\"
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = pathTPM_temp
    fnameTPM_temp = "export.xls"
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = fnameTPM_temp
    session.FindById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 11
    
    'Need to wait a couple of seconds for SAP to save - needs 2 secs, tried 1 sec but fails
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    Dim wkbTPM_temp As Workbook
    Dim wksTPM_temp As Worksheet
    
    'Open "export" file and filter for current payments
    Set wkbTPM_temp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=pathTPM_temp & fnameTPM_temp)
    Set wksTPM_temp = Workbooks("export.xls").Worksheets("export")
    
    'Format file
    With wksTPM_temp
        .Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Delete
        .Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Delete
        .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
         With .Range("A1:O1")
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Environ("UserName")
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        End With
    End With
    
    Debug.Print pathTPM_temp & fnameTPM_temp
    
    With wkbTPM_temp
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "copy"
    End With

    Dim wksTPM_copy As Worksheet
    Dim LR_hidden As Long
    
    Set wksTPM_copy = Workbooks("export.xls").Worksheets("copy")
    
    wksTPM_temp.Range("A1:" & wksTPM_temp.Range("K1").End(xlDown).Address).Copy wksTPM_copy.Range("A1")
    
    'Get LR for copy to claims file below
    LR_Copy = wksTPM_copy.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Find Open Claims file to paste data into
    Dim wbcount2 As Long
    wbcount2 = Workbooks.Count
    
    For i = 1 To wbcount2
        If Workbooks(i).Path & "\" & Workbooks(i).Name Like "*" & wks_TPM.Range("Q2") & "*" Then
            wkb2 = Workbooks(i).Path & "\" & Workbooks(i).Name
            wkb2_fname = Workbooks(i).Path & "\" & Workbooks(i).Name
            wkb2_name = Workbooks(i).Name
            Debug.Print wkb2_name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim wkbClaim As Workbook
    Dim wksClaim_clearing As Worksheet

    Set wksClaim_clearing = Workbooks(wkb2_name).Worksheets("Clearing")
    
    LR_clearing = wksClaim_clearing.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wksTPM_copy.Range("A2:K" & LR_Copy).Copy wksClaim_clearing.Range("A" & LR_clearing + 1)
    
    'Kill temp "export" workbook
    wkbTPM_temp.Close SaveChanges:=False
    

    strMinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - dblStartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")        'stops timer - Determine how many seconds code took to run
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & strMinutesElapsed, vbInformation        'Msg box for elapsed time & Claims consldaited

    ResetSpeed
    
    
Exit Sub
   

ErrRef: MsgBox ("Liar!!!" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Adam - 1" & vbCrLf & "You - 0")
   
ResetSpeed

Exit Sub

''Handler1:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Waypoint1
''Handler2:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Waypoint2
''Handler3:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Waypoint3
''Handler4:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Waypoint4
''Handler5:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Waypoint5
''Handler6:                  'jump done, error handling is now disabled
''    Resume Next

   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your program behave when you make these changes?

```
...
Dim g
For g = 66 To 71
  On Error Resume Next
  Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
  If err.number = 0 Then
     On Error Goto 0
     If Amt <> "" Then
        'Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text
        Debug.Print Amt & CStr(g)
        Exit For
     End If
  Else
     On Error Goto 0
     Debug.Print CStr(g) & "nope"
  End If
Next g
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: This works! Could you help me in understanding this a bit better please. I know `no error = 0` but don't see how this was any different (except from the error handling) to my previous code...

Comment: The illustrated program construction turns off system error treatment for only a single command. The shutdown of the system error handling in your program happens for a whole series of commands. And that can eventually lead to unwanted reactions.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I wasn't aware of this and will now review my odes goin forward to allow for the single command error treatment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following change first:

```
...
Next_g:
        'On Error GoTo 0
    Next g

On Error Goto 0

...
```

Then you can see where is the actual error.

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: Tried your suggestion - error is still on the same line `Amt = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & CStr(g) & ",11]").Text`. If I have the `g` range from `67 - 71` it works, but I do know that sometimes the amount could be on `66` thus wanting to have all bases covered